# Filter two vocabularies in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, views

I want to do a similar filter like at this page: 
http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?industry=Technology

I have two vocabularies. Countries and Industryes. 
We chose an industry, and then we choose from what country we want the company. 
It show me a firms, witch are in one industrie, an example Technologies and in one country, an example Afrika. Not all countries, not all industries. Can someone help me with this? I´m sorry for my english. I will be grateful for any help. I use Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a standardfeature of Taxonomy. In fact, it is not a part of the *concept* Taxonomy, regardless of using Drupal at all.

However, you can achieve this, somehow with Drupal taxonomies, when you abuse them as Facets.

For that, you need to set up your views and provide quite some hacks, amongst others, you need to add some PHP to your views.

From a birdseye, here is what you do:

- You create views that list only nodes with term X as parameter: `/mypage/12` to show only pages with term 12.
- You allow Drilling down in that list, by nesting the parameters: `/mypage/12/35` to show only nodes with BOTH term 12 AND term 35.
- You abuse the views header to present links with options: links to the nested options: on `mypage/12` it would show, amongst others, a link to term 35, a link to `/mypage/12/35`.
- The code to select these options can be simplified by making a second view: a view that lists all options nested under 12.
- In the header of the first, node, view, you then place some PHP that fetches and renders these links.

For a long and detailed howto, I think [burningbird has a good manual](http://realtech.burningbird.net/content-management/planet-drupal-entries/drupal-views-and-taxonomy-pages)